# Why does this code not work from localhost?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the following to get some information from my server:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://myapp.com/status/",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"))
  }
}).always((data) => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(data.responseText))
})
```

It works, when I run it in the console on one of my server's other pages, but not when I run it in a console from localhost - I get a password prompt. I have set my CORS headers, but it seems that when I inspect my request in the Network tab, the Authorization header is simply not being set at all. What's going on?

Here are the CORS headers I'm sending:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

Comment: The options request with every CORS request doesn't contain the headers. Is your server also checking options-requests on this header?

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst I've added the exact CORS headers I'm using, does that help?

Comment: Yes, you need to add OPTIONS also for the Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Comment: And add "Authorization" to the list at Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst I've amended the headers, but still no luck I'm afraid

Comment: wat does the server returns? 500 error? 404? etc

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst 401, and the browser pops down a password field. I checked the request and the Authorization header is simply not there.

Comment: Can you try to remove beforeSend, and try to set headers with the headers object. like : `headers: { 'Authorization', 'bas ....' },`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158896/discussion-between-user31415629-and-jasper-seinhorst).